# How to get Terracotta server status code that it is running or not with java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, terracotta

I have one spring framework project and in that Terracotta server is configured. Now I want to get status of Terracotta server that it is running OR not.I have searched on net but I am not able to get solution. Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Like the Terracotta version and where you want to have the running status - inside the application or more generally.

Comment: Terracotta server's version is 3.7.2 . I want running status of terracotta server in separate java program so through that i am able to know the status of terracotta server. I have terracotta server's URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that in java **Boolean.getBoolean("tc.active");** you can get boolean variable true/false that terracotta server is running or not..

**Reference** : http://terracotta.org/documentation/3.7.4/bigmemorymax/technical-faq

Note that **Boolean.getBoolean("tc.active");** has one problem. If you are **getting always TRUE value after terracotta server is DOWN** than use the following solution.

**Reference** : http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/7214.page

Thats it.